# Proving there are infinite real numbers that make the polynomials of degree 2021 with integer coefficient equal 0.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, solution-verification

The question is:
Let S be the set of all real numbers $c$ with the property that there exists a nonzero polynomial $f$ of degree 2021 with integer coefficients such that $f(c) = 0$. Prove that $|S| = \aleph_0$

My solution:
I try to construct a set P with all polynomials of degree 2021 with integer coefficient,
P={$_0+_1+_2_2+...+_{2021}_{2021}|_∈,=0,1,2...2021$}, and since → is a surjective relation, I can prove ||≤||=|$^{2022}$|=||=$ℵ_0$

My question is:
how to prove $|P|\ge\aleph_0$, and is there any missing part in my proof? Do you have any easier way to prove this?

Comment: Hint:  Every integer is in $S$

Comment: Your proof that $|S|\leq\aleph_0$ is incorrect; you've shown that $|P|\leq\aleph_0$ but since all you know about $|S|$ a priori is that $|S|\geq|P|$, that's not enough to show that it's equal to $\aleph_0$. (I'm assuming that you mean to say that $S\mapsto P$ is surjective. If you mean that $P\mapsto S$ is a surjective relation then you need to be much more specific, because there isn't an obvious or immediate mapping from $P$ to $S$.)

Comment: (To expand on that last point and provide an example: what element of $S$ would you associate with the polynomial $P=x^{2020}-1$? Why _that_ one?)

Comment: For any c in ||, there exists an f in||, isn't it a surjective relation from P to S?

Comment: @Rafael Many $c$ in $S$ can share the same $P$. You haven't defined, for a given $P$, _what_ element of $S$ you're assigning to it.

Comment: (For an extreme example, imagine that $P = \{0,1\}$ and $S=\omega$, with the relation being '$p$ is the parity of $s$'; for every $s\in S$ there's a $p\in P$ that is its parity, but you _haven't_ assigned an element of $S$ uniquely to each member of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Construct the following polynomial

$$P_c(x) := x^{2020} (x-c) = x^{2021} - cx^{2020}$$

For every $c \in \Bbb Z$, this is a polynomial of degree $2021$ in integer coefficients with root $c$. Hence, you can easily see that

$$|S| \ge |\Bbb Z| = \aleph_0$$

To see that $|S| \le \aleph_0$, note that $S$ is a subset of the algebraic numbers (since we're limited to polynomials of degree $2021$). As that set is countable, $S$ is at-most countable.

Both together give the desired equality.

Comment: Should the number above the product sign be 2021 instead of 2020?

Comment: @Rafael: No, that would give a polynomial of degreee $2021$. EeveeTrainer, even simpler is $P_c(x)=(x-c)^{2021}$ (or $(x-c)x^{2020}$).

Comment: @Rafael No. If the upper limit were $2021$, then the degree of $P_c(x)$ would be $2022$, not $2021$. Perhaps more straightforward, though, would be to define $P_c(x)=x^{2020}(x-c)$.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you! Could you please explain or answer how to prove ||≤ℵ0, too? Someone said that my proof is incorrect and I can't understand Eevee's answer clearly.

Comment: @Rafael: you have edited that part out of your question!

Comment: @TonyK you can see it now.